# Angular 'orderBy' not working with complex ng-options

Tags: angularjs

Can't get `orderBy` to work when I have a complex `ng-options` statement.

This does not sort the `<select>` options as expected:

`ng-options="p.proxyType for p in proxyOptions track by p.proxyType | orderBy:'proxyType'"`

http://plnkr.co/edit/60ZbBP1mg5VvlMwrvOZS?p=preview

Comment: Tell me what, why you track by proxyType. I thing it will cause a duplication error. It's not unique

Comment: `proxyType` is unique is this illustration. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, it should be...

```
<select ng-model="data.selected" 
        ng-options="p.proxyType for p in proxyOptions | orderBy:'proxyType' track by p.proxyType"></select>
```

In other words, `track by` part should be the last one. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Nes7dnKEvcT4NJUgazE?p=preview).

Comment: In other words, `(p.proxyType | filters) for p in (proxyOptions | filters) track by ...`

Answer (score 0):

Track by should always be last, so :

```
ng-options="p.proxyType for p in proxyOptions | orderBy: 'proxyType' track by p.proxyType
```